# How to configure NextJS to respect the Expires or cache-control header when doing a fetch request

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch-api

The `fetch` calls I do in my NextJS totally ignore the `Expires` and `cache-control` headers of my server. I found out I can configure the cache with `next.revalidate` but actually I would like that the server decides how long to cache the response. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible so far.